# cakephp date.timezone is a few hours behind

Tags: php, cakephp

i have installed cakephp 1.3 which uses the following:
Apache Version :2.2.21
PHP Version : 5.3.8
MySQL Version : 5.5.16.
the Problem is when i echo the following

`echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');`
i get the time a few hours back than my local  time( the machine time is set to my country time which australia).
when i make a change in php.ini file and set the date.timezone = UTC + 10 i get the correct local time but i also get alot of warnings.

**Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Australia/Melbourne' for '10.0/no DST' instead in C:\wamp\www\cakephp\lib\Cake\Cache\Cache.php on line 515**

Please help thanks

Comment: i checked the core.php file and found nothing

Comment: ... i don't want to disable the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify timezones as offset to UTC like "UTC+10" as you mentioned in your post. You have to use one of the valid timezone strings. Pick your continent [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) and you will get list of valid timezone strings.

So for eg. in core.php you have to do:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Melbourne");
```

Change the timezone string to any other valid timezone string you like. By the way CakeTime::listTimezones() will also give you the list of timezones.

Edit: You can probably specify the timezone as offset to UTC but shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

> If you’re getting timezone related error from PHP uncomment one line
>   in app/Config/core.php:
>
> ```
> <?php
> /**
>  * Uncomment this line and correct your server timezone to fix
>  * any date & time related errors.
>  */
>     date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
> ```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#fire-it-up

Comment: i have uncommented the line. but i still have the same problem. the date is 5/10/2012 which is OK, but time is 10 hours back (my pc time is 3:43PM) and the echoed time is 5:43am. thanks

Comment: So change the timezone "UTC" to match your local timezone.

Comment: ADmad,as i mentioned above when i change it from UTC to AEST or AEDT it works but i get a lot of warnings (see above)

Comment: Check my post, you surely won't get any errors if you set the timezone using date_default_timezone_set() in your core.php

Comment: ADmad, thanks it worked, but just one more question this only fixed the cakephp application, but if i echo the time in a different application it show the 10 hour different time, thanks

Comment: You can set it in your php.ini to make it global